# char not recognized in parameter

Tags: c++, char

I'm programming in C++ using Visual Studio. Wherever I try to specify something as "char" in my arguments, like this:

```
getData(char& mStatus, int& nOfChildren, double& salary, double& contribPension);
```

I get 2 errors. First, it says I must have ')' before char, and that getData() does not receive 0 arguments.

I tried just a null argument instead all throughout my code (which is practice using namespaces), and it runs. However, with those changes it doesn't print the return statement from taxAmount() to the screen. So maybe the arguments have to be named? I've looked EVERYWHERE and have no idea what the issue is. This is the rest of main:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Heading.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
getHeading("Assignment 8");
deductions::getData(char& mStatus, int& nOfChildren, double& salary, double& contribPension);
calculations::taxAmount(char mStatus, int nOfChildren, double salary,
             double contribPension);
getClosing();

}
```

Comment: Err. You're mixing function calls (such as `func(1,2)`) with function declaration (such as `getData(char& mStatus,...)`.

Comment: :p I realize you're new, but that is funny!  Don't include type when you're calling functions.  For example: deductions::getData(mStatus,nOfChildren,salary,contribPension);  You have to declare those variables somewhere first...

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `char` as the parameter type. You try to declare methods inside a function and leave out the return value.

The compiler thinks, this is a method call and therefore rejects the `char` by insisting on a closing parenthesis `)`.